# Angular 2: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular

I am getting the below errors while making the get request .

> Module "'node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
>   Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I have tried all the possible solution provide in StackOverflow but it did not work for me.

**code:**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { IEmployee } from './employee';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {
        private  _url : string = 'apiData/employeedata.json'
        constructor(private _http: Http) { }
        getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {

            return this._http.get(this._url)
                .map((response: Response) => <IEmployee[]>response.json());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your `rxjs` version?

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.5
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Comment: Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.5
@angular/cli                      6.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.5
@schematics/angular               0.6.5
@schematics/update                0.6.5
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3

Answer (score 2):

You are using **Angular 6** not Angular 2
You are using `HttpModule` which is **deprecated** you should use **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)** instead
In new `HttpClientModule` JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed using `res.json()`
Before you can use the `HttpClient`, you need to import the Angular `HttpClientModule` into root Module.

```
    import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
//.......
```

You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.

Type checking of response can be done by  using the type parameter

`Http` returns an `observable` and We can tell the `HttpClient.get` to return `response` as IEmployee type When we use `http.get<IEmployee[]>(...)` then it returns the instance of `Observable<IEmployee[]>` type.

In your component `subscribe` to `Observable<IEmployee[]>` to get instance of IEmployee

**In your service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { IEmployee } from './employee';
    import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


    @Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {
        private  _url : string = 'apiData/employeedata.json'
        constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
        getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {

            return this._http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);

        }
    }
```

Apart from it RxJS v5.5.2+ has moved to **[Pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)** to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators

New Import

```
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and change `.map(...) to .pipe(map(..))`

PS:**NOT required if you are using `HttpClientModule`**
 **Modified Code**

```
 return this._http.get(this._url).pipe(
                    map((response: Response) => <IEmployee[]>response.json()));
```

I would suggest you to stop  using `HttpModule` and go for `HttpClientModule` Instead

Comment: Hi if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.