# How to solve this error Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx'

Tags: angular

Failed to compile.

./src/app/services/admin.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx' in 'C:\project\test-m\angular\src\app\services'

package.json
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",

Comment: What versions of Angular and RxJS? Please give a [mcve] that actually helps people recreate the issue.

Comment: angular 6.0.5 and rxjs 6.00

Comment: Then why are you trying to import from `rxjs/Rx`? I'd recommend reading https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md; at the very least you need `rxjs-compat`, but you should really migrate properly.

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  getRegister(data) {
    let headers = this.setHeaderWithAuthorization();
    return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl + 'getregister', data,{ headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());

  }---this is my service page

Comment: So read the docs I linked above - that won't work any more. See also https://update.angular.io/.

Comment: If you are on angular 6 you should not use `HttpModule` it is deprecated use `HttpClientModule` instead, Refer this [How To](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544998/5695162)

Comment: i dont know howto solve...i will try for this docu ....but..ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\project\test-m\angular\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\index.js'
ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\project\test-m\angular\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\operators\index.js'

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

in place of

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: Works, Problem is presented after update to angular 8 from 7

Answer (score -3):

i resolved the issue

### app.module.ts

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [

```
HttpClientModule,
```

],

### service.ts

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

```
  getlogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/login', { username: username, password: password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            return user;
        }));
}
```

### components.ts

```
this.adminService.getlogin(this.login.email,this.login.password)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data)
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
```

refer this link:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#app-module-ts